# Virtual monitor?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I know there are programs that manage a virtual desktop and Ubuntu directly supports it,
  but this is a bit more programmaticaly directed question. (Not for [SO] because I got ask-banned by asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938053/search-for-image-in-minimized-window) :().

I need a virtual Monitor which is inaccesible for the user, it must be an expansion of the screen which is accesable for pixel-searches only. And where I can place a window(by command-line moving). Something like this:

[image]

Comment: 1) Why would you need a virtual monitor for that? Why not just start the program with the script as a service? 2) What did you try yourself? What is the point where things failed?

Comment: @Hennes How to that? And will I be able to search the pixels of it?

Comment: A monitor does not do any pixel searches. A program (or script does). Programs (in general) can run just fine without any window or any display. In fact you are probably running a dozen of them when you just boot the computer. For more details about that, look up 'services'.  As for pixel searches: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Does the program look for pixel patterns in a file? Does it render something on a screen and do you try to OCR/recognise that? ... Without knowing that there is no way I or anyone else can give a proper answer.

Comment: @Hennes I use a program to search for pixels in the screen and click on them, untill now I had to put the window where it looks for pixels visible, but with a virtual monitor i'd be able to do other thing while the sript is running. Pixel searches are searches for visible pixel combinations(images) on the screen.

Comment: Perhaps Xnest. It gives you a display in a window. Or there is also a headless X which does not even use a window but I don't remember the name of it. They used it for automating Open office which needs a X display even for document format conversion.

Comment: Dand D. Omg that is awesome! Can I have that on windows?

Comment: @DanD. Forgot the @ ^

Comment: @user3163282 On windows, the only equivalent is a remote desktop connection to the local machine, and that is only supported on some editions of windows.

Comment: @DanD. *Sigh* :( if you can't use with al windows, it's useless for me :(, But I searched for the terms you gave me and got this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-desktop/my-pc-thinks-it-has-a-second-monitor-that-is/143bfbd0-58c8-475d-86cc-2abf20ba269c looks like he accidentaly managed what I need?